# Checkmarx marks API route as "Potentiel reflected XSS"

Tags: java, spring, api, jpa, xss

The code sniffer Checkmarx detects this API route as "Reflected XSS all client".

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public @ResponseBody Language getLanguage(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return languageService.getById(id);
}
```

The getById implementation uses JPARepository

```
// Language service
@Override
    public Language getById(String id) {
        try {
            return repo.findById(id).orElse(repo.findById("en").get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I do not understand why it would be flagged as such, considering the use of findById() in the repository would simply retrieve nothing if the input is invalid (or am I wrong ?), and the user won't receive anything "corrupted".

Should I simply ignore this and consider this as a recommendation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely ignored the warnings from Checkmarx.

It seems that it is a very simplified static analyzer and often doesn't understand the context it is in. Therefore there are a lot of false alarms that this tools gives us.

This same tool marked "Clear password in code" when in reality it was a comment with `pswd: client password`

In the end, judgement is necessary on your project to decide wherever it is pertinent or not.